# array with double index (from 2 other arrays)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table in my db:

```
 table
 ----------
 reportID (fK)
 cityID(fK)
 parameterID(fK)
 value
```

Same city can appear more times in the same report.

I would like to retrieve the values and echo them (later in the file) as $value[cityID][parameterID] i.e. to echo value for parameterID=3 for cityID=100 I have only write

```
 echo $value[100][3]
```

what I did so far is

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE reportID=##

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {      
   $selectcityID_array[] = (isset ($row['cityID']) ? $row['cityID'] : "");
   $selectparameterID_array[] = (isset ($row['parameterID']) ? $row['parameterID'] : "");  
   $selectvalue_array[] = (isset ($row['value']) ? $row['value'] : "");    
}
```

How do I combine the 3 arrays now? Probably with a the array_combine function?

```
array_combine($selectvalue_array , ($selectcityID_array, $selectparameterID_array);
```

**EDIT:**

Ps Always after the

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE reportID=##
```

would it be possible to have an array with all the cityID for the the same reportID, including cities that figure more times in the same report?

ie array(100,120,133,100,180...)

I tried array_unique function, but it cuts out cities that figure more than once. I also tried array_chunk, but with no luck...

I need to echo:

```
CITY    PARAMETER 1                   PARAMETER 2

cityID  $value[cityID][parameterID]   $value[cityID][parameterID]

cityID  $value[cityID][parameterID]   $value[cityID][parameterID]

......   .......................      ....................
```

Thanks!!

Comment: do you want to get 'value' from table row by `cityID` and `parameterID` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as shown below:

```
...
$selectvalue_array = [];

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   if (!isset($selectvalue_array[$row['cityID']])) {
       $selectvalue_array[$row['cityID']] = [];
   }      
   $selectvalue_array[$row['cityID']][$row['parameterID']] = $row['value'];
}
...
```

Now, you can access a certain row value in the following way:

```
// of course, if there is confidence that '100' as cityId and '3' as parameterId exist
echo $selectvalue_array[100][3];
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question... do you think woud it be possible to have an array with all the cityID for the the same reportID, including cities that figures more times in the same report?

ie array(100,120,133,100,180...)

Comment: you're welcome. As for your edit: you can add the additional array `$reportCities = [];` and then, within the loop accumulate all the cities ids (even repeated ones) for the specified `reportId` `$reportCities[] = $row['cityID']`.

Comment: Sorry Roman, but $selectvalue_array doesn't work if I have a city twice in my report : if $selectvalue_array[100][3] is present 2 times, with different values, how does the system know which one I'm referring to?

Comment: what can I say, you didn't understand me correctly. You can NOT use a repeated `cityId` values in such hierarchy as `reportId -> cityId -> parameterId -> value`, cause arrays in PHP don't allow repeated keys! That's why I have advised an  additional array `$reportCities = [];` in my previous comment. Be conscious.

Comment: sorry Roman, but I don't understand how to combine the  `$selectvalue_array` with the  `$reportCities = []` to make a table like in my edited question. Would be possible for you to edit your answer with the code? It would be really helpful for me, thanks!!  (I looked everywhere on the web for a tutorial explaining how to echo a table, but I couldn't find... I was probably not using the right keywords for my search. I thought I could do it with the `$selectvalue_array[][]` but now I'm back at square one because of the repeated cities... ). Thanks!